# Why does reloadData work but not reloadItem?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I have a NSOutlineView that works great. If I change the model, the outlineview is updated when I call: `[self.myOutlineView reloadData]`. However, when I profiled my program it seems that 10% of the time is used on updating my outlineview. I therefore tried to update only the model object that has changed and not the entire outlineview by calling `[self.myOutlineview reloadItem:myIndexPath]` where `myIndexPath` is the NSIndexPath to the node in the outlineview I am updating.  However, nothing happens when I call `reloadItem` while everything works perfectly when I call `reloadData`. Does anyone have any suggestion for what I am doing wrong or how to solve this problem?

Thanks! Cheers, Trond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outline view's `reloadItem:` requires the item parameter, not an index path. So, pass the actual item. `NSIndexPath` is not used by `NSOutlineView` class at all.

Comment: Thanks! So would I call the reloadItem from within e.g. `- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item` like `[self reloadItem:item]`? Or can I get hold of the item object from outside of the outlineview delegate?

Comment: Item is the object you provide in the `- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView*)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item` data source method. It is your primary data. Outline view does not make it, it gets is from the data source.

Comment: Perfect @Davyd! I had sent the wrong type of object to my reloadItem: and thats why it did not work. After I changed the object to be a NStreeNode object the following worked: `NSTreeNode *mytreenode=[self.myOutlineViewController.myTreeController.arrangedObjects descendantNodeAtIndexPath:myIndexPath];`and `[self.myOutlineViewController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadItem:) withObject:mytreenode waitUntilDone:NO];`. Using `reloadItem` instead of `reloadData` decreased the time use from 10% to 0.3% and it now takes 12 seconds to finish my program compared to 22 s earlier.Thanks!